# open fetch and close cursor DB2

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

I'm using DB2 cursors. My table contains 4 rows. Bellow is the list of instructions that i have done on my code:

```
1- OPEN CURSOR
2- FETCH CURSOR
3- FETCH CURSOR
4- CLOSE CURSOR
5- OPEN CURSOR
6- FETCH CURSOR
7- CLOSE CURSOR
```

Supposing i have 4 rows on my table that i want to have them in my results.
In the 6th step (FETCH CURSOR) , will i have the 3rd row of the table or i will have the first row because i have closed the cursor.
i mean the cursor is saved after closing or not.

Comment: if you have four rows, you should have four FETCH statement executions.  OPEN and CLOSE are expensive operations and should be done once.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc it's not the response that i'm looking for. My question is "can i fetch the 4th row after closing and opening the cursor" ? Cursor recognize the row where it stops before closing it ?

Answer (score 0):

> i mean the cursor is saved after closing or not.

From the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=statements-close)

> If the cursor is reopened, it is again located at the beginning of the rows to be fetched.

**However**, you can code a *row-positioned* phrase on your [FETCH statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/13?topic=statements-fetch) using the ABSOLUTE option to position your cursor at a particular row in the result set.

```
        Working-Storage Section.
        77  C1-POSITION PIC S9(009) COMP-5 VALUE +1.
        EXEC SQL DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR [...] END-EXEC.
        [...]
        Procedure Division.
            EXEC SQL OPEN C1 [...] END-EXEC
            *> fetch row 1
            EXEC SQL FETCH ABSOLUTE C1-POSITION C1 [...] END-EXEC
            ADD 1 TO C1-POSITION
            *> fetch row 2
            EXEC SQL FETCH ABSOLUTE C1-POSITION C1 [...] END-EXEC
            ADD 1 TO C1-POSITION
            *> fetch row 3
            EXEC SQL FETCH ABSOLUTE C1-POSITION C1 [...] END-EXEC
            ADD 1 TO C1-POSITION
            EXEC SQL CLOSE C1 END-EXEC
            [...]
            EXEC SQL OPEN C1 [...] END-EXEC
            *> fetch row 4
            EXEC SQL FETCH ABSOLUTE C1-POSITION C1 [...] END-EXEC
            ADD 1 TO C1-POSITION
            EXEC SQL CLOSE C1 END-EXEC
```

You will need appropriate error checking (not included here) to ensure you have not attempted to retrieve a row whose absolute number exceeds the number of rows in the result set.

The comment by @GilbertLeBlanc regarding the relative expense of OPEN and CLOSE is something to keep in mind.

**Caveats:** I don't have a mainframe to test this on, code is freehand and only provided as an example, I am just crafting an answer based on the IBM documentation.